# NavigationView и OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, material-design

В общем есть у меня картинка в NavigationView и приложение, которое используется вместо лаунчера. Порезал я эту картинку и раскидал по папкам mdpi, hdpi и т.д. В итоге (если я нажму несколько раз на кнопку HOME) приложение падает из-за этой картинки (а может и из-за NavigationView) по ошибке OutOfMemoryError, вот логи:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=65536KB, Allocated=60841KB)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.my.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)    
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)    
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`MainActivity.java:70` указывает на `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
Вообще эта ошибка появляется, если картинка имеет большое разрешение (верно?), хотя на самом деле картинка имеет разрешение 612×441 для hdpi и 816×587 для xhdpi. Приложение тестирую на двух реальных устройствах. На эмуляторе ошибка не появляется. Как избавиться от этой ошибки? Перерыл 10 страниц в гугле, но решение не нашел.

**UPDATE:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:orientation="vertical">
// падает из-за этой картинки
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/android_background" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: какие модели дивайсов, на которых вы тестируете?

Comment: Nexus 4 и HTC One S

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы вы добавили код, где вы кладете картинку, возможно вы каким то нехитрым образом кладете ее снова и снова? Или перересовываете. С картинками и OOM извечная проблема...:(

Comment: добавил разметку. да ничего особенного, использую стандартную разметку.